# (LP Duality) What is the dual of this linear-programming

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems

My question is pretty simple and I'm just asking because I'm confused. I don't know what should I do if a variable is not present in the constraints.

> What is the dual of this? (note that we have both $x1$ and $x2$)
> \begin{align} &&&\min{}&   &\quad{} x_2 \\ &&& \text{s.t.}& & x_2 =
>  0 \\  &&&& x_1&,  x_2 \geq{} 0 \\ \end{align}

Comment: Rewrite the model with each variable in each constraint and objective, with a 0 coefficient if needed.  Then apply the rules for generating the dual.

Comment: Thank you @TickaJules